# Javascript/ES2015, count the number of occurrences and store as objects within an array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am extracting data from a JSON feed and am trying to count the number of times each name (name_class) occurs.

I want to return an array of objects in the following format, where count refers to the number of times the name appears:

```
myArray = [{name:"John", count: 5}, {name: "Sarah", count: 2}, {name: "Oliver", count: 3}];
```

So far I have the following, but this does not count the number of occurrences, it simply adds another object to the array;

```
   let namestUi = {
    renderNames(names){
        var counter2 = [];
        let namesFound = names.map((name) => {
          let {name_class} = name;

            if(counter2.name == name_class){
              counter2.count++;
            } else { counter2.push({name: name_class, count: 1}); }
        });
        console.log(counter2);
        return namesFound;
      }
    };
```

This is building the array of objects but not counting the number of occurrences.

Comment: counter2 is an array... And you are referencing name property

Comment: `counter2.count++` this line is weird.

Answer (score 2):

```
function count(names){
    // Count occurrences using a map (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)
    let map = new Map();
    for (let name of names) {
        map.set(name, (map.get(name) || 0) + 1);
    }

    // Transform to array of { name, count }
    let result = [];
    for (let [name, count] of map) {
        result.push({name: name, count: count});
    }

    return result;
}

count(["a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "a"])
// [{"name":"a","count":3},{"name":"b","count":2},{"name":"c","count":1}]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems in how you use your counter variable. You access properties as if it is a plain object, but you defined it as an array. Also your `map` callback function is not returning any value.

You could use this code which uses a `Map` to key counters by name, and then applies `Array.from` to convert that Map to an array of objects as you requested:

```js
let namestUi = {
    renderNames(names){
        return Array.from(
            names.reduce( (counters, {name_class}) =>
                counters.set(name_class, (counters.get(name_class) || 0) + 1),
                new Map() ),
            ([name, count]) => ({name, count})
        );
    }
};

let result = namestUi.renderNames([
    { name_class: "John" },
    { name_class: "John" },
    { name_class: "Frank" },
    { name_class: "John" },
]);

console.log(result);
```